# trying to access object property makes it empty - javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm working on somebody's code and the author isn't available rn.
I have an object with another object nested in it, and it's been retrieved from api call.
The problem is when i do a console.log on the parent object it shows the nested object in it properly but when i try to log object.object i'm getting an empty object.
Any idea on what could cause this problem?

```
console.log(product) ==> {id: 1, extra:{name:'example'}
console.log(product.extra) ==> {}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: That's not possible, it's a massive project and there are so many inheritances and dependencies in between. I can't tell which part is producing the problem

Comment: I think every time I've seen this, the problem was that the browser logs show the object in the current state, not the state when it was logged. You can try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(product))` to see how it looks at the time of logging. If it is also empty there, then it is likely modified later on (between logging, but before displaying in the browser console logs). [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yav04uko/) shows what I mean if you look at the browser console logs

Comment: I try to reproduce your problem. The code works like expected. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds8kf31L/1/)

Comment: @A_A thank you, this was really helpful. Actually it is also empty in string format.

Comment: Glad it helped. I will search for the corresponding question and mark it as a duplicate